# How to customise the tabs at the bottom of a feed chatter component

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

How do I customise (add/remove) the different tabs at the bottom on the chatter component. In my case I would like to remove the tab **Text Posts** and add **Odd Jobs**. See image below:

[image]

Comment: Hello please review this once [Customize Chatter Profile Pages
with Profile Tabs](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_profile_tabs_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this in **Feed Filter Options** section in Feed Item for a page layout.

Go to Set up -> Object Manager -> Find and open object -> Open page layout where you want to make this change -> **Click on Feed View on the top** -> Modify Feed Filter Options you want .

[image: Feed View]

[image: Feed Filter Option]

Hope this Helps !